# Script to incremental backup MySQL workbench in linux

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench, mysql

I have an issue related to how to incremental backup MySQL workbench.
Can anyone tell me the script to backup this? 
I want to back up all day and keep incremental with difference file. 
Can anyone give me the sample script about that?

Thank,
Veasna.

Answer (score 0):

The binary log (mysql-bin.log) is essentially an incremental back-up. It allows you to revert back to a previously stable database state.

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.0/en/backup-policy.html

Making Incremental Backups by Enabling the Binary Log,

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/backup-methods.html

Comment: thank for your reply but it still got error when I add my.conf file. after I add this file I cannot restart mysql service. Do you have any clue for that.

Answer (score 0):

May i know from where you are restarting the service, through command prompt Or from your control panel.

Share your error message here, you Will get further details if anyone knows.